# how to update the second element's attribute on XML?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

May i know how to update the second element's attribute using linq to xml? I do write some code but it doesnt work, it only update the user attribute....I'm sorry for asking this kind simple question.

My XML:

```
<Settings>
<Settig>
<User id="1" username="Aplha"/>
<Location Nation="USA" State="Miami" />
<Email>user1@hotmail.com</Email>
</Setting>
</Settings>
```

My Cs :

```
public static void saveSetting(MainWindow main)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load("Setting.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> query = from p in document.Descendants("User")
                                      where p.Attribute("id").Value == "1"
                                      select p;


        foreach (XElement element in query)
        {               
             string i = "New York";
             element.SetAttributeValue("State", i);
        }

        document.Save("Setting.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select the `Setting` elements; you can still select on `id=1`, like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> query = from p in document.Descendants("Setting")
                                  where p.Element("User").Attribute("id").Value == "1"
                                  select p;
```

Then select the `Location` element before updating:

```
foreach (XElement element in query)
{    
    element.Element("Location").SetAttributeValue("State", "New York");           
}
```

Comment: @0070 Yes, I think so -- you need to select the `Location` element first, then set the attribute.